# Compose Modifiers not being honored

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have some Composeables swapped by a when statement in the setContent block of a form.  One of those child composeable's top level part is a column with horizontalAlignment set to Alignment.CenterHorizontally, and verticalArrangement set to Arrangement.Center.  However, when composed, the column's children are put in the upper lefthand corner not the center.  Any way to fix this? Example Code:

```kotlin
setContent {
    var status by remember { mutableStateOf(Status.State1) }
    when(status) {
        Status.State1 -> {
            //background color does not change
            Surface(modifier = Modifier.background(Color(0xFF000000)))
        }
        Status.State2 -> {
            //none of the parameters are applied
            Column(
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                modifier = Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Max)
            ) {
                Text(text = "I should be in the center")
            }
        }
        else -> {}
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: Here's the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method

```kotlin
setContent(ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
    //your composeable
})
```

automatically inflates the main composeable to max screen size.  However, the the setContent {} method does not.  Adding Modifier.fillMaxSize() to the main composeable fixes the issue.